# ¿Como arrojo más datos y detalles a un error del error_log? - PHP

Tags: php

tengo una duda simple pero no puedo manejarla, dado que no conozco el uso del try catch.

Tengo una variable, es un string, vamos a suponer que es una fecha.

```
$string1 = "2021-06-01";
```

Este dato se carga dinamicamente, por lo que a veces pueden llegar datos basura.

```
$string2 = "Hola soy un dato basura";
```

Como el dato esperado, es realmente una fecha, yo le hago un explode, para por ejemplo, obtener el mes.

```
$mes = explode("-", $string1);
echo $mes[1]; //Salida: (string) "06"
```

Obviamente, si llega un dato basura, no podrá realizar el explode.
Esto arroja un error, que llega al archivo `error.log` de PHP.
Lo que quiero, es que al momento que ese error llegue... imprimir la variable en el log.
De este modo, saber CUAL es el dato basura que me está llegando y evitarlo.

Intente hacer algo como esto, pero no ocurre nada.

```
try {
    $mes = explode("-", $string2);
    echo $mes[1];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log("Has tratado de imprimir un dato basura, el dato es: " . $mes, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php#refsect1-function.explode-returnvalues) no genera una excepción (que es lo que puedes capturar dentro de `try ... catch`) cuando el caracter a buscar no se encuentra en la cadena, en tu caso, devuelve un arreglo con un solo elemento y, por otra parte, tratar de acceder a un elemento inexistente en el arreglo solo genera un mensaje de notificación.

Resultado de `explode()`: falso y tratar de acceder a `$mes[1]`:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Resultado de `explode()`: arreglo vacío o un solo elemento y tratar de acceder a `$mes[1]`:

> Notice: Undefined index 1 in...

Analiza el resultado de explode, debería contener 3 elementos (año, mes y día), de lo contrario, guarda el error y finaliza el script:

```
$mes = explode("-", $string2);
if(count($mes) != 3) {
    // Crear mensaje con dato de origen
    $msg = "Has tratado de imprimir un dato basura, el dato es: $string2";
    // Guardar error en log
    error_log($msg, 0);
    // Lanzar excepción... ¿Es necesario o basta con die/exit?
    throw new Exception($msg);
}
echo $mes[1];
```

Una mejor opción sería crear tu función para [manejo de excepciones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-exception-handler.php):

```
function myException(Exception $e) {
    // Guardar mensaje
    error_log($e->getMessage(), 0);
    // ¿Finalizar script?
    die('Ha ocurrido un error inesperado, estamos trabajando para solucionarlo a la brevedad posible.');
}

// Registrar función para manejo de excepciones
set_exception_handler('myException');
```

Después, cada que haya un error y consideres necesario guardar la información, simplemente lanzas la excepción:

```
$mes = explode("-", $string2);
if(count($mes) != 3) {
    // Lanzar excepción
    throw new Exception("Has tratado de imprimir un dato basura, el dato es: $string2");
}
echo $mes[1];
```

Finalmente, una observación: Las excepciones son el resultado de errores que no permitirían que el script continúe ejecutándose y, en tu caso, lo ideal sería realizar validaciones y enviar los mensajes correspondientes para que el usuario sepa lo que debe corregir.

Answer (score 0):

Peudes usar estas opciones, la mas simples son incompletas. Por ejemplo:

Chequear si el resultado son 3 partes:

```
$mes = explode("-", $string2);
if (count($mes) != 3)
    error_log("Fecha no valida ". $string2)
}
```

El problema es que esto tambien permite resultados como "aaa-bbb-ccc", lo que no seria valido.

Una mejor forma es usar una ***expresion regular*** llamando a `preg_match()` y chequear el texto antes de procesarlo, cuando la expresion tiene reglas especificas como una fecha, la expresion puede ser bastante complicada:

```
if (!preg_match("^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$")) {
    error_log("Fecha no valida ". $string2)
}
```

Esto tampoco es totalmente a prueba de fallas, ya que no considera bisiestos ni meses que no tengan 31 dias.

Para validar fechas es mejor usar una funcion dedicada a ello, como `date_create_from_format()` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-create-from-format.php). Si la conversion falla, `$date` sera `null`, evaluando a falso.

```
$string1 = "2021-06-01";
$date = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d",$string2);
if (!$date) {
  error_log("Fecha no valida ". $string2);
} else {
  $mes = $date->format("m");
}
```